# Is there a difference between testing the style attribute of an element and the css value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a single-page website that uses arrow buttons on each side to scroll to different pseudo-pages. The left arrow has the CSS value `visibility: hidden;` so that the use doesn't scroll into empty space. The button becomes visible once the user scrolls to the right, but I want to hide it again when the user scrolls back to the "homepage". I'm using jQuery to test the `left` attribute like so:

```
if($('#box').css('left') == '0%') {
    $('.left').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

Inspect Element on Firefox shows me that the left value when I want the button to disappear is indeed `0%`, but it actually appears in the HTML tag, as `style="left: 0%;"`, because the value is assigned by the scroll mechanism I coded in JavaScript. Is there a different way to test for these `style` values versus a value on a CSS stylesheet?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Is there some problem with the code you've shown?

Comment: There might be, but I'm just asking if the `.css()` method in jQuery works if the attribute is stored in the HTML tag of the element and not on a CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Why are you asking us? Does it work for you or not? Why not print out the result and see for yourself?

Comment: The code is correct, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: If it doesn't do anything, it's not correct then is it?

Comment: getter `css()` method returns computed style, don't expect it to work consistencly across browsers, i mean for testing returned value.

Comment: You need to use `getComputedStyle` to get styles that come from CSS.

Comment: `getComputedStyle` can give you computed css properties  for pseudo elements too , `:before` and `:after`

Comment: @evandewey, check the console https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/e2u1qL75/

Comment: For some reason the inline CSS style attribute on the element I'm manipulating is different than the value `console.log()` returns. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to the following:

```
 console.log('left is now = '+$('#box').css('left'))
 if($('#box').css('left') == '0%') {
   $('.left').css('visibility', 'hidden');
 }
```

This will give you three pieces of information:

1) are you actually hitting that if statement
2) when it does hit, what is the actual value being returned (and yes you may want to try computedStyle)
3) is the value what you expected.

Armed with this info, you can quickly debug your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I used this to realize I have a different problem.